# Magento 1.9 . 3 .8 : merchant countries drop-down list dosent have jordan

Tags: magento-1.9, countries, merchant

Merchant Country (jordan) Not Present in the drop down list.

How I can add this in dropdown ?

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Jordan Country is already there in Magento. It May possible it is not selected in Allowed Country.

You can allow this from system configuration.

For this from backend Go to **System > Configuration > General**

Here you have the **Allow Countries** dropdown. You can select allowed countries from here.

Comment: thank you for your answer.yes i can find it under System > Configuration > General ... but i need it in the merchant country field under System > Configuration > payment method > paypal